# How do I invoke a Sails.js controller function from a file in the project root?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am building a Sails.js application that runs on Heroku. I need to use [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) to run a "CRON" job every few hours. The scheduler only allows me to run a single command so I have it setup to run `$ node sendEmails.js` every 1 hour.

The issue is, sendEmails.js is not a part of the core Sails.js project and I need it to invoke a function inside my ReportsController.js file. How exactly do I go about doing this? I don't want to copy the controller logic to sendEmails.js because it has a lot of dependencies to the database and other services which I can't duplicate. For context:

```
/**
 * ReportsController
 *
 * @description     Server-side logic for managing reports
 * @help            See http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Controllers
 */

module.exports = {

    // I need to call this function from sendEmails.js which is in my project root
    generate: function(req, res) {
        // Logic for generating reports
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in several ways:

1. (Better) Create a service and then invoke the service name like `Myservice.myfunction` or even `sails.myservice.function`. Your service, as the name says, will be available for every controller and can be used to centralize code that will be used globally. Take a look : [Sails Services](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/services). You can then invoke your service inside a controller, then your service can (or cannot) do option 2 if it suits you.
2. (Not very good) Inside a controller or service, do a manual `require` for the path of your file. Like this `let myfunctions = require('../folder/myfile.js')` and then invoke the functions like ``myfunctions.myfunction(nargs)`. Don't forget to use`module.exports = {...}`.

Comment: @paulgdm I can't really use services in this context. What I am trying to achieve is to be able to invoke some function within my sails.js app from the command line as that's the only way I can run a scheduled job in Heroku. How do I access a Sails controller function from the command line?

Comment: @Nag I see your point... Im afraid you need to edit your `app.js` file. There you can do anything when you call sails lift. Maybe it can solve your problem. But be aware, thats not the way Sails was designed to be used!!! It is a MVC framework afterwards.